# Two title pages in one document, scrbook

Tags: titles, titling

I want a second title page with the same layout but different input. 
After trying the `titling package` I got two title pages but the layout did not work anymore and some input was missing.

Any idea what I have to change?

```
\titlehead{%
  {Technische Universität Berlin\\
   Institut \\
   Lehrstuhl }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north east, inner sep=60pt]  at (current page.north east)
{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{figures/TU_logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\subject{Masterarbeit}
\title{TITLE german}
\author{\large{name} \\ \small{Matrikel Nr.: 11111} }
\date{\small{\textit{\today}}}
\publishers{
  \small{1. Gutachter: Prof. name} \\
  \small{2. Gutachter: Dr. name}\\
  \small{1. Betreuer: Dr. name}\\
  \small{2. Betreuer: Dipl.-Ing. name}
}

\maketitle  %% Titelseite erzeugen

\titlehead{%
    {Techncal University Berlin\\
        Institute \\
        Chair }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=60pt]  at (current page.north east)
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{figures/TU_logo}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}


\subject{Master's Thesis}
\title{TITLE english}
\author{\large{name} \\ \small{Student Nr.: 11111} }
\date{\small{\textit{\today}}}
\publishers{
    \small{\nth{1} Referee: name} \\
    \small{\nth{2} Referee: name}\\
    \small{\nth{1} Supervisor: name}\\
    \small{\nth{2} Supervisor: name}
}

\maketitle  %% Titelseite erzeugen
```

EDIT: In case it is caused by another package I use, here are all loaded packages:

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % supported languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Umlaute
\usepackage{listings} %For R code
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} %colour setting in listing
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation
\usepackage{amssymb} % for checkmarks
\usepackage{mathtools} % math stuff
\usepackage[sticky-per]{siunitx} % units
\usepackage{float} % placement of floats
\usepackage{graphicx} %inluding pictures
\usepackage[super]{nth} % 5th of...
\usepackage{caption}  %captions for figures
\usepackage{subcaption} % Arrange many figures as one
\usepackage{array} %Table settings
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %fancy page styles
\usepackage{footmisc} % footnote options
\usepackage{enumerate} %numerated lists
\usepackage{tikz} %Add logo in upper right corner of title page
\usepackage{titling} %enables second titlepage
```

Comment: What do you mean by *layout did not work anymore and some input was missing.* Apart from `german/english` the titlepages look alike

Comment: If I print both pages, the titlehead including the logo is gone, as well as the publishers. The title is not printed in bold anymore.

Comment: Seems like the titling package overwrites the title settings too, as the layout does not work as intended if I just compile one title page as long as the titling package is activated... Is there another way to get a second title page?

Comment: Decided to create the second title page as PDF and include it as a page in the actual document. Would be grateful for another solution.

Comment: I am a little bit occupied right now, but I will look later on

Comment: @user3483945: Just omit `\usepackage{titling}` -- you don't need that package at all -- it will shown then both title pages (one after another one, each with the logo)

Comment: Where is `\titlehead` from? It sounds like you are using a non-standard class or something which customises `\maketitle`. In that case, loading `titling` will overwrite that configuration. But it is impossible to say without more information. We need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). EDIT: I see your title says Koma. You are riding rough shod over its approach and would be better advised to use its facilities rather than e.g. `fancyhdr`. If you post an MWE, we could understand better, though.

Comment: Do not use predefined title pages. Do them on your own, as the answer below says as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also had many problems with the title page in my thesis 'cause it wasn't exactly the format what I wanted and I needed some additional items on it. I solved the problem by making my own page in a separate file and including it into my document.
I explained it here yesterday: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207949/63764

Maybe it will work for you if you make 2 title pages.  germantitle.tex and englishtitle.tex and include them both into your main document.