# Change the cover page in classic thesis

Tags: titles

I am using the classic thesis template and I would like to include the names of my supervisors on the left end of the cove page but nothing seems to work. I hope that someone can help with that, for my preamble I use the following:

```
      % book example for classicthesis.sty
      \documentclass[
      % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
      % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
      %oneside,
      oneside,
      11pt, a4paper,
      footinclude=true,
      headinclude=true,
       cleardoublepage=empty
       ]{scrbook}


        \setlength{\parindent}{4em}

        %\usepackage{scrlfile}
         \PreventPackageFromLoading{mathpazo}
         %\usepackage[pdfspacing,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis}
        \usepackage{float}
         \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
        \usepackage{amsmath}


                 \title{Design of Support Tools} 
                \author{by\\
                 name} 
                \date{2014} 
               \titlehead{A Thesis submitted for the degree}

               \setlength{\parindent}{4em} 
              \begin{document} 
             \maketitle 
              \frontmatter
             \tableofcontents
              \listoffigures 


              \chapter{Acknowledgements} 
              I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This 
             research was funded by the Imaginary Research Council. 
             \chapter{Abstract} 
              A brief summary of the project goes here. 
              \chapter{Abbreviations}
               \mainmatter 

              \backmatter  
            \begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of 

            \end{thebibliography}
            \end{document}
```

Comment: [How to customize a title page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my thesis I built my own title page in a seperate file named 'title.tex' because that way it is much more flexible than using the standard title page.

here a quick example how I designed my titlepage including your title:

```
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\textsc{\LARGE A Thesis submitted for the degree}\\[1,5cm]

\begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
\textsc{\LARGE Design of Support Tools}\\[1,5cm]
\endgroup


by\\[0,5cm]
name\\[2,5cm]


\end{center}

Names of your supervisors

\vfill

\end{titlepage}
```

and in the main document include the titlepage with \input{./title.tex}

eg:

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
%titlepage
\input{./title.tex}

...
\end{document}
```

Comment: good idea, thanks a lot! I had really stuck with this issue

Comment: Little hint, line spacing is done after the paragraph is finished. I think you will prefer `\textsc{\LARGE Design of Support Tools\par}` as this is the recommended way.